# 10.04 -> 12.04 Upgrade . Server. do-release-upgrade fail. What sources to change

Tags: 12.04, server, 10.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I am current trying to upgrade a ubuntu server via ssh. I am stuck since i can not perform a do-release-upgrade. It tries maverick instead of trying 12.04

Essentially I think he is failing because 12.04 is an old release. I had to change /var/lib/update-manager/meta-release to start using old-releases mirrors instead of archive since it was failing before with another problem.

My sources : http://pastebin.com/xrFTaKjn
My /var/lib/update-manager/meta-release : http://pastebin.com/A3Zs6DYx

What is wrong?

My error:

```
Checking for a new ubuntu release Done Upgrade tool signature Done Upgrade tool Done downloading             authenticate 'maverick.tar.gz' against 'maverick.tar.gz.gpg'  extracting 'maverick.tar.gz' tar: Removing leading `/' from member names

Reading cache

Checking package manager Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree         Reading state information... Done Building data structures... Done  Reading package lists... Done     Building dependency tree           Reading state information... Done Building data structures... Done 

Updating repository information WARNING: Failed to read mirror file 35% [Working]  Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of  network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 

W:Failed to fetch  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]  , W:Failed to fetch  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.gz 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]  , W:Failed to fetch  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]  , W:Failed to fetch  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/restricted/source/Sources.gz 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]  , W:Failed to fetch  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]  , W:Failed to fetch  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.gz 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]  , W:Failed to fetch  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/main/source/Sources.gz 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]  , W:Failed to fetch  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/restricted/source/Sources.gz 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]  , W:Failed to fetch  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/universe/source/Sources.gz 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]  , E:Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or  old ones used instead. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting Reading package lists... Done     Building dependency tree    Reading state information... Done Building data structures... Done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because you are on 10.10 (Maverick) and not 10.04 (Lucid). Upgrading from 10.10 to 12.04 is unsupported, while 10.04 -> 12.04 should work.

10.10 is no longer supported, and there is no upgrade path to any supported currently release. Just backup, and reinstall.

12.04 will be supported until Aprl 2015.

To upgrade from 10.04 server to the next LTS, install `update-manager-core`, 
then edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`, and set `Prompt=lts`.

You'll obviously have to edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and reset every line back to `lucid` first.

Comment: No. lsb_release -a says: Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS. But you have a nice point, my pastebin shows references to trying to fetch Maverick updates. I do not understand why... I want to upgrade to 12.04

Comment: Looks like your system is set to upgrade to the next release, 10.10. See the edit above for upgrading to the next LTS.

Comment: For repeated upgrades over ssh without prompting, see this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/304980/165026

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest thing to do, and in practice less time consuming (although you might not think so) is to plan for this in advance and separate out your home and system directories onto different partitions. Use your home for any documents, files, scripts, and custom stuff - and keep system for things installed via dpkg or its descendents (ie: apt-get and any of the update GUIs) ONLY. If you need to change config files for X, samba, etc. keep a backup in your home directory.

If you run up gparted (use sudo apt-get install gparted if it's not already on your system), you can (to some extent) non-destructively split a single partition into two, and resize them later if you get space requirements wrong.

Once you've done that, just grab a new installer of 12.04 (I assume you want that specifically because it's LTS), and run it.

I've been following this procedure on numerous operating systems (usually putting system and home on different physical drives) and it works well.