# unattended Release Upgrade from Ubuntu Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

This question from 2013 [Can I do a Silent or Unattended Release Upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250733/can-i-do-a-silent-or-unattended-release-upgrade)

explains how to upgrades to the new stable release without prompts:

```
$ do-release-upgrade -f DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive
```

However this does not work on my system:

```
$ do-release-upgrade

Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [198 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1'261 kB]
Fetched 1'261 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
authenticate 'yakkety.tar.gz' against 'yakkety.tar.gz.gpg'
extracting 'yakkety.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Get:1 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease [247 kB]
...
```

However, 
    $ do-release-upgrade -f DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [198 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1'261 kB]
Fetched 1'261 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
authenticate 'yakkety.tar.gz' against 'yakkety.tar.gz.gpg'
extracting 'yakkety.tar.gz'
```

and gets stuck here. It does not continue with the "Reading cache".

How to make an unattended release Upgrade from Ubuntu Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS?

Comment: How long did you wait for the upgrade to continue?  It's possible the upgrader was not able to calculate the upgrade and it exited.  If that's the case you might want to look at /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log to see what went wrong.

Comment: I waited for one hour. I see this at "/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log": "ERROR Cache can not be locked (E:Could not get lock //var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable), E:Unable to lock the administration directory (//var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?)".
However, running `do-release-upgrade` without the `-f DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive` option worked fast and fine.