# How to run do-release-upgrade without prompts

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I m upgrading Ubuntu14(trusty) to Ubuntu16.
Is there any way to `do-release-upgrade` without any prompts.
I was already try a lot of method likes,

```
do-release-upgrade -f DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive
sudo sh -c 'echo "y\n\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\n" | DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive /usr/bin/do-release-upgrade'
```

those command doesn't work for me.

Comment: The prompts are there for a reason - they protect users from a destroyed system and total data loss.  Advanced users have other options, like dist-upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, i understand what u mean. But the problem is i am going to upgrade over 100 ubuntu server, this is impossible to answer evey question for 100 machine. I know ansible may solved my problem but i need to use python fabric. if u have any idea please share me.

Comment: A mass-upgrade use case should probably be in the question. It changes the tone greatly. Does it *need* to be an upgrade? Can it be one of the many methods to mass clean-install?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I do a Silent or Unattended Release Upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250733/can-i-do-a-silent-or-unattended-release-upgrade)

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command before do-release-upgrade:

```
sudo echo DPkg::options \{ \"--force-confdef\"\; \"--force-confold\"\; \} | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local
```

Then:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -f DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive
```

That seems to fix the couple of configuration files that don't listen to the "DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive" setting in the most recent releases.

Note that this might break things, I encountered [this GRUB bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1889509) as well as some other random crashes while upgrading via this manner. I don't recommend this upgrade path for production servers.